# How can I convert an integer array (at a specific position) to an integer number?

Tags: integer

I have an integer array with three elements inside:

```
int [][] Array = new int [12][11] ;
//I initialize it with elements!
```

I want the number in position `Array[2][3]` and to store it in an `int`.

How can I do that?

Comment: I also want to convert a double number to hexadecimal!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int myInt = Array[2][3];
```

No conversion needs to be done, because your array is of type `int`.

Comment: Great, if this works for you, could you accept it as the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Is it that you want to get the element of particular index? I that is so, then you can get the element at that position in following way:

```
int x = Array[2][3];
```

If it is something else you want to do with the array please specify.